# How to write a program to print name of day corresponding to the day number given by user

Tags: python, list, printing, user-input

I want an input like If I type 1 then it will give output Sunday , if I type 2 it will give Monday. I tried this code but it is not working , plz help

```
days =["Sunday" ,"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

user_input = int(input("Enter Day"))
if user_input == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) :
    print (days[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I want to make my program simple , I am a beginner

Comment: hint: use a dictionary to store key, value pairs of numbers --> words

Comment: @gold_cy does he need to do that much?

Comment: it would be cleaner and more sustainable, yes

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Your posted code is not legal Python.  You seem to need either a dict or a straightforward index.  The appropriate step is to repeat your educational materials on those topics, so you learn how to index a list or dict.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
days =["Sunday" ,"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

user_input = int(input("Enter Day (from 1-7)"))
if user_input:
    print (days[user_input-1])
else:
    print ("Your input is not valid")
```

> With a dictionary

```
days_dict ={'1':"Sunday" ,'2':"Monday",'3':"Tuesday", '4':"Wednesday", '5':"Thursday", '6':"Friday", '7':"Saturday"}
print (days_dict[input("Enter Day (from 1-7): ")])
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it is working perfectly , you made my day bro

Comment: @HireshVerma Cheers bro!

Answer (score 0):

```
days =["Sunday" ,"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

user_input = int(input("Enter Day"))

print (days[user_input - 1])
```

This will help

Comment: can i write this like that?        print (days[user_input - 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,6 ,7])

Comment: No you can not do it like that

Comment: @HireshVerma What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Do you get a wrong result? BTW, that code is working without problems, but it would be nice if the answerer would give some explanantion what was wrong and how this problem was fixed.

Comment: My apology ,  this code is working perfectly , i have made a silly mistake in my program

Comment: @HireshVerma if you found my answer heplful then kindly upvote and accept the answer from the buttons on the left of answer

Answer (score 0):

```
day_number = int(input("Enter day number: "))

days = { 
    1:'SUNDAY',
    2:'MONDAY',
    3:'TUESDAY',
    4:'WEDNESDAY',
    5:'THURSDAY',
    6:'FRIDAY',
    7:'SATURDAY'
}

print(days.get(day_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

input("Enter a number in the range of 1 through 7: ")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35076091)